# How can I count the number of edges between connected components of a directed graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, programming

The following code:

```
Clear[g];
SeedRandom[28];
g = RandomGraph[{17, 40}, DirectedEdges -> True, 
VertexLabels -> "Name"];
SCCs = ConnectedComponents[g];
sccLargest = MaximalBy[Length]@SCCs // Flatten;
{HighlightGraph[g, Subgraph[g, sccLargest]], 
CommunityGraphPlot[g, SCCs, CommunityRegionStyle -> LightGray]}
```

[image]

I want to count the `total number` (in and out-links together) of edges between pairs of connected components, and represent the strength of linkage between the components by thickening the lines between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Outer[Total[AdjacencyMatrix[g][[#, #2]], 2] &, SCCs, SCCs, 1]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 5, 3, 30}}

or

```
Outer[Length[AdjacencyMatrix[g][[#, #2]]["NonzeroPositions"]] &, SCCs, SCCs, 1]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 5, 3, 30}}

or

```
ecounts = Outer[EdgeCount[g, DirectedEdge[Alternatives @@ #, Alternatives @@ #2]] &, 
   SCCs, SCCs, 1]
```

> {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 5, 3, 30}}

```
TableForm[ecounts, 
   TableHeadings -> {SCCs, SCCs}, 
   TableAlignments -> {Center, Center}] // TeXForm
```

> $\scriptsize\begin{array}{ccccc}
>   & \{17\} & \{8\} & \{9\} & \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14,15,16\} \\
>  \{17\} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \{8\} & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \{9\} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,14,15,16\} & 1 & 5 & 3 & 30 \\
> \end{array}$

**Update:** *using the information given in `ecounts` to adjust the thickness of the directed arrows between the SCCs:*

```
wam = Outer[Total[AdjacencyMatrix[g][[#, #2]], 2] &, SCCs, SCCs, 1] /. 0 -> ∞; 
wag = WeightedAdjacencyGraph[wam];

SetProperty[wag, 
  {PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
   VertexSize -> {v_ :> (Length[SCCs[[v]]]/30)},
   VertexLabels -> {v_ :> ToString[SCCs[[v]]]}, 
   EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> AbsoluteThickness[PropertyValue[{wag, e}, EdgeWeight]]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I was wondering how one can use the information given in the table `TableForm` to adjust the `thickness` of the directed arrows only between the SCCs.

Comment: @TugrulTemel, please see the update.

Comment: The update is just what I needed. Very nice...

Comment: I have a question to make sure that I under your `Code` above correctly. In the `code` above, you scale the thickness of the arrows by `30`, which is the number of edges in the largest SCC (i.e. `VertexSize -> {v_ :> (Length[SCCs[[v]]]/30)}` ). Am I right?

Comment: @TugrulTemel, that's right.